# How to use Config in dependency provider in Nameko?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, nameko

In `Nameko` we can use `Config` dependency provider to read config from a yaml file:

```
class SampleService:
    name = "sample"

    config = Config()

    @rpc
    def get(self, user_id):
        # I can access self.config here
        return {'user_id': user_id}
```

I have created a new `MongoDB` dependency provider which is beside config:

```
db = MongoDBDP(config.get('host'), config.get('port'))
```

The problem I have is that I don't have access to configurations here. How should I access config for `MongoDB`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is not possible in `Nameko 2`, this feature is added in `Nameko 3` which is in pre-release state:

> You can do this with Nameko 3.
>
> In Nameko 3, config is a global helper, so you can do almost exactly
>   what you have in that snippet.

You can read more here:

- https://github.com/nameko/nameko/issues/609